# Why does Heroku postgres take longer than local mysql?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, postgresql-performance

In my local development a query I make using ActiveRecord takes 1695ms including rendering the view, however on Heroku I get a request timeout with the same query, which means it takes more than 30s. Is there something I don't know about Heroku or Postgres that might cause this?

Here is the query:

```
Event.where(id: Details.select("event_id").where('email like \'%gmail%\''))
```

There are no indexes on the email attribute for the Details table.

Locally the explain_threshold is set to nil but I doubt it would have a problem with a 1.6s query anyway.

The amount of data in not terribly different, not like 1000 in one and 1000000 on the other, which is why I assume it should take about the same time.

Comment: What does the query look like? Any indexes? Have you checked the EXPLAIN output? How much data do you have in MySQL? How much in PostgreSQL? Are you sure the database is causing the problem?

Comment: I just edited the question based on your questions

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info for guidance on providing appropriate details. The *SQL* query (not the Rails code) and an `ANALYZE` or, preferably, `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` of that query would be the minimum needed.

Comment: Which query in `select events.* from events where events.id in (select event_id from details where email like '%gmail%')` is taking all the time? I'd guess the inner one.

Answer (score 2):

The amount of data here is significant, because:

```
in (select ... where email like '%gmail%')
```

cannot use an index. It's a guaranteed seq scan on the entire table. The more rows you have, the slower it'll be.

Try changing the query a bit by using this trick:

http://postgres.cz/wiki/PostgreSQL_SQL_Tricks#LIKE_optimalization